# Cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Annotations differs on glue classes found

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber

When I want to run Features scenario of cucumber, I faced following exception:

```
Caused by: Cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Annotations differs on glue classes found
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because all testStep classes should have same count  of annotations as following :

**Check number of annotation in all TestStep classes that should be same**

```
 private void checkAnnotationsEqual(Class<?> stepClassWithSpringContext, Class<?> stepClass) {
        Annotation[] annotations1 = stepClassWithSpringContext.getAnnotations();
        Annotation[] annotations2 = stepClass.getAnnotations();
        if (annotations1.length != annotations2.length) {
            throw new CucumberException("Annotations differs on glue classes found: " + stepClassWithSpringContext.getName() + ", " + stepClass.getName());
        } else {
```